# Conditions on ideal b for fields or integral domains

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A$ be a ring and $b$ be an ideal of $A$. Prove that
1. $A/b$ is a field $\iff b$ is maximal
2. $A/b$ is an integral domain $\iff b$ is prime

I figure that the first is derived from the fact there is only the trivial ideal in $A/b \iff b$ is the only ideal in A containing $b$.

It is the second proof I am having trouble with. Intuitively I realise that from the definition of integral domain, $\forall x,y \in A/b, xy=0 \implies x=0$ or $y=0$, means something about the cosets of A that make up $A/b$, but I can't quite see it. I want to avoid use of equivalence classes and use the coset notation instead.

I have begun by stating the definition of an integral domain and then do I need to claim that $x=0 \implies x=x+b$ where x is an element of b in A? Or is x just an element of A? 
If $x \in b$ then the rest would be clear since ideals are closed under addition so $x+b \in b $ which, once the same argument is applied to y also, forms the definition of prime ideal.

If this is correct, I do not understand how to prove the opposite direction without simply repeating the same proof backwards.

Comment: It might be worthy to explicate the reason for me (and maybe others) to vote to close the question, and it might be the probable reason for these downvotes. That is to say, you have to write down your efforts when you post questions. It's a convention and a formal etiquette. It may not be that reasonable, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Regarding your added part:* Let $A$ be a commutative ring identity (this assumption is missing, you should add this one also) and let $I$ be an ideal of $A.$ Then the zero element (i.e. additive identity) of $A/I$ is $0 +  I$ and $a + I = 0 + I \Leftrightarrow a \in I.$

Suppose $A/I$ is an integral domain. We want to show that $I$ is a prime ideal. For this we need to show that if $x, y \in A$ are such that $xy \in I,$ then either $x \in I$ or $y \in I.$ Let $x, y \in A$ and assume that $xy \in I.$ Now in the quotient ring $A/I,$ we have $(x+I)(y+I) = xy + I = 0 + I.$ But it is an integral domain. So either $x+I = 0 + I$ or $y+I = 0+I.$ Hence either $x \in I$ or $y \in I.$

Next assume that $I$ is a prime ideal. Let $x+I, y+I \in A/I$ be such that $(x+I)(y+I) = 0+I.$ Then $xy+I = 0+I \Rightarrow xy \in I \Rightarrow$ either $x \in I$ or $y \in I \Rightarrow$ either $x+I = 0+I$ or $y+I = 0+I.$ Hence $A/I$ is an integral.

*Note:* This proof is exactly same as the existing answer (by *pre-kidney*). The only difference is that I use the notation $x+I$ instead of $[x]$ (because you want to use cosets instead of equivalence classes, though these two are same).

Answer (score 2):

**$A/m$ is a field iff $m$ is maximal:**

The Noether Correspondence states that the ideals containing $m$ are in bijection with the ideals of $A/m$. Thus $A/m$ is a field iff its only ideal is 0 iff the only ideal containing $m$ is $m$ itself, i.e. $m$ is maximal.

**$A/p$ is an integral domain iff $p$ is prime:**

Let $[x]$ denote the equivalence class in $A/p$ corresponding to an element $x\in A$. Then $ab\in p\iff [a][b]=[0]$. Hence the condition $[a][b]=[0]\implies [a]\text{ or }[b]=0$ is equivalent to the definition of primality.

Comment: Interesting: I have never heard the correspondence theorem called by Noether's name. I searched the first 8 pages of google hits and found exactly one similar usage in a homological algebra book by Osborne. If you know where you got the idea, I would be interested in the source.

Comment: @rschwieb: Here is some of links: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem https://books.google.co.in/books?id=1AZfvv-Ava0C&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=Noether%27s+correspondence+of+ideals&source=bl&ots=uoKrqDUsve&sig=HUVcE9yg7jiaT10ljTW2XG9HGe4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=quq8VITcC8OsmAXCm4LYBA&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Noether%27s%20correspondence%20of%20ideals&f=false I first came to know about it in T.Y.Lam's book Serre's Problem on Projective Modules. There he used the term *Noether's Isomorphism Theorem.*

Comment: @krish ok, there are actually hits for that usage. I'm a bit surprised any special name would be attached to a theorem like this. You would think that the same theorem for groups would be well known before this, and that results like it would be considered "folklore."

Comment: All other google hits besides the one I mentioned used Noether correspondence in connection with her theorem on invariants.

Comment: Here's the explanation I heard in my algebra course. Emmy Noether was influential in the development of modern algebra, but unfortunately not enough things were named after her. In order to rectify this, people (relatively recently) decided it would be fitting to name the Noether correspondence in her honor, even though she did not discover it per se. The ideal correspondence didn't have a special name before that!