# Is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/ \langle x^3+3x+2 \rangle$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**Let $φ(x)= x^3+3x+2\in \mathbb{Z}[x] .$ Is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/ \langle φ(x) \rangle$ field?**

If $φ(x)$ was not irreducible: $\exists a(x),b(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]-\{+1,-1\}: φ(x)=a(x)b(x)$. That means that $degφ(x)=dega(x)+degb(x)\implies 3=dega(x)+degb(x).$

- If $dega(x)=0,\ degb(x)=3\implies a(x)=k\in \mathbb{Z}[x]-\{+1,-1\},\ b(x)=αx^3+βx^2+γx+δ$ and if we equate the coefficients, the system has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}-\{+1,-1\}$. So:
- If $dega(x)=1,\ degb(x)=2\implies a(x)$ has roots in $\mathbb{Z} \implies φ(x)$ has roots in $\mathbb{Z}$, contradiction.

So, $φ(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x].$

We know that:

*1. If $F$ field, $f(x)\in F[x]$: $$f(x)\ \text{is irreducible in}\ F[x] \iff \langle f(x) \rangle \text{is maximal of}\ F[x] \iff F[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle \text{is a field}$$
 2. If $R$ is a PID then $f(x)\ \text{is irreducible in}\ R[x] \iff \langle f(x) \rangle \text{is maximal of}\ R[x]$.*

Can 1.or 2. help us?

Comment: Your 2. is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second statement is incorrect. For a simple example, $f(X)=X$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, but $(X)$ is not a maximal ideal because it is strictly contained in the proper ideal $(2,X)$.

The same problem occurs in your example. While $\phi(X)$ is irreducible, the ideal $(\phi(X))$ is not maximal because it is contained in $(\phi(X),2)$.

Comment: You are right. I did a mistake: $R$ PID does not imply $R[x]$ PID. Right?

Comment: That's right, and $R=\mathbb{Z}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: And how can we examine in these cases ($R[x]$ is integral domain but not a PID, not a field) if this quotient is a field?

Comment: @Chris:  The quotient of a commutative ring $S/I$ is a field if and only if $I$ is a maximal ideal.  See [this previous Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1110200/conditions-on-ideal-b-for-fields-or-integral-domains).

Comment: So, could you please tell my how do we check if $\langle φ(x) \rangle$ is maximal?

Comment: See the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: You are right again. Thanks a lot.